# angular js: ng-submit does not hit controller

Tags: angularjs, servlets

I have used *AngularJS* and *Servlet*. On clicking on the Submit button, the data entered will just be shown in the URL bar but the Credentials Servlet couldn't be reached. There is no error shown. I have included my code below. Could anyone please tell me why the servlet cannot be reached?

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
 var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);

 formApp.controller('formController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
   $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:9090/UserAuthentication/Credentials',
    data : JSON.stringify($scope.user),
    headers : {
     'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
   }).success(function(data) {
    alert("Controller is hit!");
   });
  };
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
  <h1>User Details</h1>
  <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
   UserName: <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="user.username">
   <br />Password: <input name="password" type="password"
    ng-model="user.password"> <br /> <input type="submit"
    value="Submit">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Credentials Servlet:**

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

@WebServlet("/Credentials")
public class Credentials extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Credentials() {
        super();
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String jsonData = " ";

        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonData += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(jsonData);
    }

}
```

Comment: any console error messages on the browser ?

Comment: [edit] the angular `cdn` with valid one. `<script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Is your serverlet located on the same domain? If not, then it is a cross-domain issue and you need to use CORS.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your suggestions. The servlet was not hit when I tried from eclipse internal browser (although I'm not sure why). When @Sampath asked for console logs, I tried to run the code from google Chrome and the code worked. :)

Comment: These were the errors found in IE8 (eclipse internal browser) console-'Node' is undefined  angular.min.js, line 174 character 433
 Object doesn't support this property or method  index.html?username=abc&password=123, line 7 character 2

AngularJS custom elements are not supported by IE8.(Referred to: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)